# How to copy file of env variable to another file

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I am executing bash commands inside a yaml file. I have set an env variable SECRET which point to a yaml file in my home directory, and I want to copy the content of this yaml file to another file, as follows:

```
cp "${env.SECRET}" "${env.PWD}/templates/secret.yaml"
```

I have tried many solutions such as cat, less, cp, echo but none of them worked.
cp did not work as I get cp: cannot stat '': No such file or directory, while cat copies the relative file path of the env variable

Comment: Cannot replicate. AFAIK `env.SECRET` is *not* a valid name of a variable in Bash. I expected `bad substitution`, but this did not happen in your case. Either your shell is not Bash or the code you posted is not the code you run. Please review and [edit] maybe.

Comment: If using Bash: check Bash Guides at www.tldp.org for acquiring knowledge from novice to advanced. Old but still good enough for this.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I am executing bash commands inside a yaml file.

Comment: What YAML file? There's no standard for putting shell commands in a YAML file. It's all about what the program that loads it does with its contents.